# Map color change php to .js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, leaflet

I am working on a USA map with states to which states have available properties by changing the color of the state.
I am using Leaflet for the map and have used the Interactive Choropleth Map (https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) as a basis to build this.

I have added "availability":"2" to the us-states.js file, this is where the number of properties will be shown. I would like to insert a php query 
into the .js file to pull the number of properties for that state.  Here is a sample from the us-states.js file so that you can see the layout:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"02","properties":{"name":"North Carolina","availability":"2"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-131.602021,55.117982],
```

And I am using this to change color:

```
// get color depending on population density value
function getColor(d) {
return d > 1 ? '#e1cb7f' :
               '#173e34';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 1.9,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.availability)
        };
}
```

I have added this to the functions.php file:

```
wp_register_script( 'scount', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets  /js/us-states.js' );

// Localize the script with our data that we want to use
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'property',
'fields' => 'ids',
'meta_query' => array(
array(
  'key' => 'state',
  'value' => 'NC'
)
)
);
$results = new WP_Query($args);
$completed = count($results->posts);
wp_localize_script( 'scount', 'completed', $completed );

// The script can be enqueued now or later.
wp_enqueue_script( 'scount' );
```

And I using this to get the result into the .js file:

```
alert(completed);
```

I am getting the result working, this is the output when I view in developer tools:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var completed = 2;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This is the page where the map is located:  https://www.thekeithcorp.com/interactive-map/

But it is not changing the map state color!  Am I calling incorrectly in the js file?  Pulling my hair out, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT

I have isolated the problem to the alert(completed); added to the js file. the page breaks when I add the alert to the js file. Any ideas on how I should add this to the .js file?

This is how it is added:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"37","properties":{"name":"North Carolina","availability":alert(completed);},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.978661,36.562108],[-80.294043,36.545677],[-79.510841,36.5402],[-75.868676,36.551154],[-75.75366,36.151337],[-76.032984,36.189676],[-76.071322,36.140383],[-76.410893,36.080137],[-76.460185,36.025367],[-76.68474,36.008937],[-76.673786,35.937736],[-76.399939,35.987029],[-76.3616,35.943213],[-76.060368,35.992506],[-75.961783,35.899398],[-75.781044,35.937736],[-75.715321,35.696751],[-75.775568,35.581735],[-75.89606,35.570781],[-76.147999,35.324319],[-76.482093,35.313365],[-76.536862,35.14358],[-76.394462,34.973795],[-76.279446,34.940933],[-76.493047,34.661609],[-76.673786,34.694471],[-76.991448,34.667086],[-77.210526,34.60684],[-77.555573,34.415147],[-77.82942,34.163208],[-77.971821,33.845545],[-78.179944,33.916745],[-78.541422,33.851022],[-79.675149,34.80401],[-80.797922,34.820441],[-80.781491,34.935456],[-80.934845,35.105241],[-81.038907,35.044995],[-81.044384,35.149057],[-82.276696,35.198349],[-82.550543,35.160011],[-82.764143,35.066903],[-83.109191,35.00118],[-83.618546,34.984749],[-84.319594,34.990226],[-84.29221,35.225734],[-84.09504,35.247642],[-84.018363,35.41195],[-83.7719,35.559827],[-83.498053,35.565304],[-83.251591,35.718659],[-82.994175,35.773428],[-82.775097,35.997983],[-82.638174,36.063706],[-82.610789,35.965121],[-82.216449,36.156814],[-82.03571,36.118475],[-81.909741,36.304691],[-81.723525,36.353984],[-81.679709,36.589492],[-80.978661,36.562108]]]}},
```

HELP!

Comment: It looks like (based on whats loaded in scripts on the page) That your js file is not being included. If your code that you pasted in the question is exactly how it is in your php file I'm going to assume this is breaking the include: ` '/assets  /js/us-states.js' )` There are erroneous spaces.

Comment: I did miss that, I have now included the us-states.js, but still now working :-(

Comment: Meant to say, still not working

Comment: It looks like Alabama is a different color now.

Comment: Yes I manually added 2 to the .js file, to make sure that my color is working.  But still cannot get "alert(completed);" to work in the js file.  If i test in web developer console, the alert is working and showing 6 which is how many available properties in NC.

Comment: am I calling it correctly in the .js file: "{"type":"Feature","id":"37","properties":{"name":"North Carolina","availability":"alert(completed);"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.978661,36.562108]....."

Comment: It looks like your alert is in a string, which isn't going to actually call the alert. Remove the quotes from around it.

Comment: I tried that and I get a blank screen!

Comment: ^ That issue is probably because it is not a valid value. I'll try to take a better look tonight.

Comment: Anybody have a solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using this:
    ( JSON.stringify(completed) )

Without the ;