# leaflet markers using geoJson

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am trying to get markers to show on map for each state.  I am getting no markers showing.
This is my geoJson:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","availability":0},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}},
```

I am using this to get the markers:

```
geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon});
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
var myIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'https://www.thekeithcorp.com/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS- master/assets/images/4096-200.png',
iconSize: [32, 37],
iconAnchor: [16, 37],
popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});
```

I tested to make sure that icons can be added using this:

```
var marker = L.marker([37.8, -96]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        sidebar.toggle();
    });
```

and that works.  But I cannot get any icons to show on the map, any ideas on what I have done wrong?

What I want to achieve is when clicking on the icon, it opens the sidebar listing all the available properties in that state.  as you will see if you click on the icon I added using:

```
var marker = L.marker([37.8, -96]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        sidebar.toggle();
    });
```

This is a link to the map:  https://www.thekeithcorp.com/interactive-map-1/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map color change php to .js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829984/map-color-change-php-to-js)

Comment: @MartinZeitler while the question you refer to is indeed from the same user and looks to be about the same project, OP clearly describes a different objective: showing a Marker here, changing a color there.

Answer (score 0):

`pointToLayer` option of Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group factory is only used for `"Point"` type Geometries, whereas in your GeoJSON data sample you have only a `"Polygon"` type Geometry.

If you want to convert your polygon (State) into a point, you should either refactor your GeoJSON data, or use a runtime library to compute a "center" of your polygon (e.g. a centroid, etc.).

Comment: calculating the center of a Polygon appears to be quite some processing overhead: https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc manually defining a center Marker at the visual center might already suffice, because those states won't change much.

Comment: It is totally up to you how you determine these centers.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding a new layer and putting the markers on this new layer, had to manually add the lat and lag coordinates could not read from the json file:

```
 var shelter1 = L.marker([34.1,-81.4],{icon: myIcon}).on('click', function () {
        sidebar.toggle();
    });
var shelter2 = L.marker([35.4,-79.3],{icon: myIcon}).on('click', function () {
        sidebar1.toggle(sidebar1);
    });
var shelterMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup();

shelterMarkers.addLayer(shelter1);
shelterMarkers.addLayer(shelter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SheltersMarkers to include all of your leaflet marker or simply use a runtime library to compute the center of your map and where to place the marker.